# Задача.Информатика.10 класс.Python

Tags: python

1. Для строительства двухмерной пирамиды используются прямоугольные блоки, каждый из которых характеризуется шириной и высотой. Можно поставить один блок на другой, только если ширина верхнего блока строго меньше ширины нижнего. Самым нижним в пирамиде может быть блок любой ширины. По заданному набору блоков требуется определить, пирамиду какой наибольшей высоты можно построить из них.
2. По заданному набору блоков требуется определить, пирамиду какой наибольшей высоты можно построить из них. Формат входных данных В первой строке входных данных задается число N – количество блоков ( 1 100000   N ). В следующих N строках задаются пары целых чисел wi и i h ( 9 1 , 10   w h i i ), разделенные пробелом – ширина и высота блока, соответственно.
3. Формат выходных данных Целое число – максимальная высота пирамиды

[image: вот входные ,выходные данные]

Хотелось бы знать как использовать первую строчку в цикле и тд,как прочекать количество ?

зачем мне первая строчка(количество блоков) когда я могу просто открывать их циклом for построчно
вот что сделал

```
a=open("in.txt").read()
for word in a :
     print(word,end="")
```

в файле все то что написано в инпут

вывод:

```
3
3 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

тогда зачем мне первое число в инпуте?

Comment: Хм... Это точно школьная задачка? Смахивает на олимпиаду - размер ввода 10^5, поиск оптимума.

Comment: В 10-м классе ещё не проходили цикл for?

Comment: Странно, мне про чтение таких файлов рассказывали в школе ещё в девятом классе. Неужели вам по какой-то причине не рассказали?

Comment: @Эникейщик нет нет все проходили но я не понимаю зачем там перваястрочка,когда я могу просто построчно файл прочитать

Comment: @MBo нет мы такие в классе решаем

Comment: `зачем там первая строчка,` Чтобы сразу задать размер массива. В Питоне не слишком актуально. в других языках будет оптимальнее.

Comment: @MBo именно в питоне получается не актуально? и можно начинать сразу со второй строчки?

Comment: В Питоне массивов встроенных нет, только списки. Можно сразу задать список на всю длину и потом записывать прочитанное значение в очередной элемент, а не добавлять. Но скорость у интерпретируемого языка всё равно не фонтан, и вряд ли это даст заметное ускорение.

Comment: @MBo окей спасибо я понял

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строка с количеством нужна потому что:

- Во многих языках необходимость чтения до конца значительно усложняет задачу, а целью как правило является алгоритм, а не умение реализовывать ввод-вывод (на него могут встречаться отдельные задачи).
- В случае потоковой обработки входных данных, их общее количество может потребоваться для предварительной инициализации неких данных (размеров массивов, либо заполнения чего-то начальными значениями или ещё чего-то).

Что касается самой задачи, то она решается довольно просто:

- блоки, имеющие разную ширину, всегда можно выстроить в башню
- среди блоков с равной шириной логично выбирать самый высокий

Однако:

- 10<sup>5</sup> - это слишком много для тупого квадратичного решения, следует выбрать алгоритм пооптимальнее, для чего можно воспользоваться хэш-таблицами или сортировкой.

У меня в решении всего 5 строк (ну из тех, которые не пустые):

https://ideone.com/N8pMWg

```
d = {}

for a in range(int(input())):
  [h,w] = map(int, input().split(" "))
  d[h] = max(d.get(h, w), w)

print(sum(d.values()))
```

Comment: Я бы добавил, что если задачка олимпиадная, то скорее всего участник волен использовать любой ЯП. А так, как в некоторых ЯП нужно объявлять массив с заранее известным размером, отсюда и первая строчка.

Comment: @SimonOsipov, вроде во втором пункте написано? Причём, первым вариантом в скобках.

Comment: Ох, да. Прошу прощения, моя невнимательность.

Comment: @SimonOsipov, я код добавил)

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо,вот ты гений конечно